# Record a short blob audio with Alexa using nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, blob, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a skill that will record 5 seconds of my voice and send it to my database as a blob with Alexa. (It's mainly for voice recognition.. I am using Azure Speaker API)
I have spent a lot of time trying to find if there is an specific way to do it with Nodejs and Alexa but I didn't find anything.
Currently I have this project in javascript so I am wondering if it would be possible to use what I have? Because I won't have the browser to allow my microphone, etc.. so I am not sure if it would work with Alexa.
If someone has an idea or have worked with getting audio to db from Alexa, please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is get user input as voice and as per my knowledge and finding, Alexa (alexa skill kit) doesn't allow you to get raw user input in anyway.

Comment: Correct. I found this out a little later. thank you!